# Get route geometry from google maps

Tags: google-maps, api, transit

Is there any way to get the geometry line from google maps where you ask for a route?

I would want to get the blue line in this image, in order to get some of them programatically.

I know that I can get transit information from goole API, but I do not know if there is any way to get the geometry.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from the `directionsService` will give you an array of points in `overview_path` in each route. Following is the code sample for better understanding

```
       directionsService.route({
            origin: routeFromMarker.getPosition(),
            destination: routeToMarker.getPosition(),
            avoidTolls: false,
            avoidHighways: false,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                var myRoute = response.routes[0].overview_path;
                for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.length; i++) {
                    routeMarkers[i] = myRoute[i];
                }
                var linePath = [];
                $.each(routeMarkers,function(key,location){
                    linePath.push({lat: parseFloat(location.lat()), lng: parseFloat(location.lng())});
                });
                routeLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: linePath,
                    strokeColor: "#f45017",
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 3,
                    map: map
                });  
            } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
```

You can use this points to make a polyline and use its geometry.